# Create a PHP database for records using cronJob and SQL to Update database by shifting values to the right every night

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row

I am trying to run a CronJob PHP script upon asking a prior question on how to run a PHP script every midnight. Since then I have been stumped on a rather insignificant seeming issue. I have read several articles on getting rows from databases, echoing values, etc and have been implementing the code. But it seems they weren't quite meant to be run a php file. So here is the code

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pointsmanager');
$before0d = "SELECT * FROM points WHERE today_points";
$before1d = "SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE 1d_before";
$before2d = "SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE 2d_before";
$before3d = "SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE 3d_before";
$before4d = "SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE 4d_before";
$before5d = "SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE 5d_before";
$before6d = "SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE 6d_before";
$before7d = "SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE 6d_before";

UPDATE points_history
SET 1d_before = $before0d, 2d_before = $before1d, 3d_before = $before2d, 4d_before = $before3d, 5d_before = $before4d, 6d_before = $before5d, 7d_before = $before6d,
WHERE condition;
?>
```

Here's what I want to do. I want to create a history log of points a user got day by day. In one database, I want it to select a column called today_points and store it in a variable:

[image: view the database called 'points']

Then, I want it to store every value of the week from the database in a variable.

[image: see the database 'points_history']

And finally, Update points_history by shifting all of its current values to the right

[image: See it here]

and getting the value of a column called 'today_points' from another database called 'points' and putting it in '1d_before' (So every midnight, all the values shift one to the right and 'todays points' is now one day before) Can anyone show me how to do this in PHP. I honestly tried my best by doing the snippet above. But it doesn't work. Anyone show me the code to anything similar would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn about DB normalization. If your column names have numbers in them then it's a sign your schema is not normalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Dharman said, you need to normalize your table to store values in separate rows rather than columns. However, if you need a solution on how to do this in existing structure then here's the query,

```
UPDATE points_history 
SET
    7d_before = 6d_before,
    6d_before = 5d_before,
    5d_before = 4d_before,
    4d_before = 3d_before,
    3d_before = 2d_before,
    2d_before = 1d_before,
    1d_before = (
        SELECT 
            today_points
        FROM
            points
        WHERE
            user_id = '123'
        )
WHERE
    user_id = '123';
```

Let's say you want to update it for user ID '123'. In order to shift values to right, we'll first copy 6th day value to 7th, then 5th to 6th, then 4th to 5th and so on. At the end we will update first day value by selecting it from `today_points` table.

Here's the working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da3561/1)

Comment: what is user id?

Comment: How's your data stored? Is there any ID or both the tables `points_history` and  `points` have only one row?

Comment: one row on both tables. It could change.

Comment: If only one row. then remove both the `WHERE` clauses from the query.

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but this is a sql file right?

Comment: This is `MySQL` query which you need to integrate in your `PHP` code and execute it.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: You need to learn basics first. Here's the link to get you started https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: I read it before but don't know how to use it in this case

Comment: `$sql = "QUERY"` Put entire query in double quotes.

Comment: Doesn't work, when running the script, nothing happens to the db

Comment: Like I said you need to get the basics clear first. Identify the error script is throwing and go from there.